# SSH Paramiko-Python interactive script-Need to highlight a line from the list and select it

Tags: ssh, paramiko, python-3.6

I am using paramiko for ssh interactive commands. I am able to successfully send all the required commands. I am stuck on one issue. i need somebody help to automate this task.
Issue is on output, i will get 4 options, from this options, i need to move to the required option by using arrow keys and then press enter button to select that option.
Please let me know if anybody knows about this.

```
import paramiko
import time
import os


ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('server',port=22,username='user',password='pass123')
print("connected to the linux machine from windows machine.")

channel=ssh.invoke_shell()

channel_data = str()

while True:
    if channel.recv_ready():
        channel_data += channel.recv(9999).decode(encoding='utf_8', errors='strict')
        os.system('cls')
        print("##### Device Output #####")
        print("\n",channel_data)
        print("\n #####################")
    else:
        continue

    time.sleep(5)

    if channel_data.endswith('[root@home ~]# '):
        channel.send('somecommand\n')
    #highlight and then press enter button to select that option. please help for below code
    ifelse channel_data.endswith('I am trying to choose this option from the list'):
        channel.send('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to send the keycode. for down arrow key, "[B 1b 5b 42" is key code.

Below is the link for complete list of keycode mapping.
http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hlkeycodes.html